# Proof of McKay correspondence without classifications

Tags: rt.representation-theory, quivers

$\DeclareMathOperator\SU{SU}$I am wondering if there is any known proof of the McKay correspondence (I will give the precise statement that I mean by this) that doesn't use the classification of Dynkin quivers or of finite subgroups of $\SU(2)$. Explicitly, I want to prove, without using the classification of Dynkin quivers or the classification of finite subgroups of $\SU(2)$, that

> For $G \subset \SU(2)$ finite, the McKay quiver of $G$ is a Dynkin quiver.

Where we define the McKay quiver as the quiver given by (nontrivial) irreps of $G$ with an arrow from $V \to W$ if $V$is a summand of $\mathbb C^2 \otimes W$ (where $\mathbb C^2$ carries the natural action of $G$ as a subgroup of $\SU(2)$).

I know that this can be done by using the machinery of Bridgeland-King-Reid, but I am hoping that someone knows a simple/conceptual proof of this fact that can be taught to students. I feel that pedagogically, proofs relying on classification results can feel ``coincidental" in a way, and I hope there is a nice proof not relying on said classification results.

Comment: Maybe pages 101-103 of [Dolgachev's notes](https://dept.math.lsa.umich.edu/~idolga/McKaybook.pdf) about McKay correspondence could be related to your question.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet This looks very nice, thank you for the reference. I will take a look and see, but it looks to have what I am looking for. Thank you!